# Arrays with bubble sort

Tags: java, arrays

My task is to sort an array (where my grades (int) are) with the Bubble Sort algorithm, and I have done that.

But I also want it to print out the names from another array that contains the following names for each grade in the same order.

How do I do that?

```
package assignment9.pkg1;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Anders
 */
public class Assignment91 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String studName = "Anders";
    int counter = 3;
    System.out.println(" welcome to student database, show informations about student" + studName);

    Scanner courseScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner gradeScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner counterScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(" Enter the number of courses");

    String[] courseArray = new String[counter];
    int[] gradeArray = new int[counter];

    for (int k = 0; k < counter; k++) {

        if (20 < counter) {

            System.out.println(" no more space");
        } else {

            System.out.println(" enter name");
            courseArray[k] = courseScan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(" Enter grade");
            gradeArray[k] = gradeScan.nextInt();
        }
    }

    int n = gradeArray.length;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {

            if (gradeArray[j - 1] > gradeArray[j]) {
                //swap the elements!
                temp = gradeArray[j - 1];
                gradeArray[j - 1] = gradeArray[j];
                gradeArray[j] = temp;

            }

        }

    }

    for (int l = 0; l < counter; l++) {

        System.out.println(gradeArray[l] + courseArray[l]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: in loop where modified order of grades modify change the order of course array

Comment: do you want to print student_name, subject_name, grade in sorted way? And do you want to take student name from keyboard input?

Comment: you must swap the element of course array in the swap block

Answer (score 0):

in loop where modified order of grades modify order of course array , too

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {

        if (gradeArray[j - 1] > gradeArray[j]) {
            //swap the elements!
            temp = gradeArray[j - 1];
            gradeArray[j - 1] = gradeArray[j];
            gradeArray[j] = temp;

            //swap the course name !
            String stringTemp;
            stringTemp = courseArray[j - 1];
            courseArray[j - 1] = courseArray[j];
            courseArray[j] = stringTemp;

        }

    }

}
```